# executor cancel pending task - help needed

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, producer-consumer

Basically, I need a machinery to have the following:

1. Fixed-sized thread pool to run tasks
2. Queue of pending tasks (requested, but not yet running)
3. Cancelling task in pending queue (task is identified by id)
4. Cancelling ongoing task
5. Given task id, query whether task is Pending or Running

Could anyone suggest best way of achieving this, especially items 3-5. I would really appreciate some code example.

Thanks.

Comment: Any attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: The answer might be in your tags :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything but task states and cancelling is standard for thread pools. Cancellations and status state could be done the following way:

```
enum TaskState {PENDING, RUNNING};

abstract class MyCallable<V> implements Callable<V>{
    protected volatile TaskState state = PENDING;

    // to make sure state is always set before running the task
    protected abstract V doCall();

    final V call(){
        state = RUNNING;
        return doCall();
    }

    public TaskState getState() { return state; }
}

...

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

Future<V> future = executor.submit(new MyCallable<V>() {
    public V doCall() throws Exception {
        //... some work ...
        if(Thread.interrupted()){
            removeFromMap();
            return null;
        }
    }
});

...

future.cancel(true);
```

To make task cancellable one needs to check `Thread.interrupted()` state during it's execution or some other logical boolean flag. After getting a future for the submitted task, `future.cancel(true)` should be called to cancel the task by interrupting it.

Comment: thanks a ton. Several questions : 1. I guess after `executor.submit` I also need to do something like `pendingMap.put(id, future);` and remove item from this map in `MyCallable.call` since I need to cancel by id 2. Do you strongly recommend using `Callable` ? I was thinking `Runnable`, since I don't need return value 3. ThreadPool is managed by android service. I need to stop service when all tasks are processed. What is the way to detect that ?

Comment: 1. Just use the `ConcurrentHashMap` and remove there is a positive test for interrupting (from inside) or when cancelling (from outside the task). 2. `Runnable` is ok 3. `executor.shutdown(); executor.awaitTermination();` First command stops accepting further jobs, second awaits all running jobs to terminate. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Regarding 3. I actually meant differently: I do want to continue to submit tasks, but when everything is processed I would need to stop the service. So I guess the right approach will be : at the end of each task check whether hashMap is empty (no running/queued tasks), if so -> stop the service. I think that should work.

Comment: This should work, I think. You might need to await termination in a separate thread running once.

Comment: Ah, your last remark looks more elegant than checking if future hashMap is empty : so, you suggest instead just have a dedicated `new Thread() { void run() { executor.awaitTermination(); [service.]stopSelf(); }` Is my understanding correct ? Is it a common practice ?

Comment: I propose to have a check `if no more jobs, 1) executor.shutdown(), 2) run once a thread to wait for termination` OR to start `java.util.Timer` which would periodically check if there are no jobs and shutdown&await threadpool's termination when needed. This is not a common practice for a thread pool, but it's ok, I think, and it's also a watchdog concurrent pattern.

Comment: Usually thread pools are used to run a bunch of tasks for a single time, i.e. submit-await termination for a local run or globally - just to have a place to drop a task to. Global thread pools listen to app shutdown hooks and die when app dies.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is in the tags. If you use a fixed thread pool ExecutorService, you can limit the number of threads that can execute simultaneously.

If more threads are submitted than can be handled, they are held in a queue.

Calling the submit() method of an ExecutorService will give you a Future object which will let you know whether the task is pending or it has been cancelled, etc

I do have a series of tutorials on ExecutorService:  http://codelatte.wordpress.com/2013/11/09/a-simple-newfixedthreadpool-example/

How to use Future object: http://codelatte.wordpress.com/2013/11/08/a-simple-cachedthreadpool-example/